# Invoke python script from another python script and set execution directory of the executed script

Tags: python

This has probably already been asked, but after some digging and not finding it, I am posting a question. I am new to Python.

Assume I have two scripts (`scriptA`, `scriptB`) in two separate directories. I would like to run `scriptA` and have it invoke `scriptB` in `scriptB`'s directory. How would I go about doing that? I have seen examples of how to invoke another python script using `os.system(...)` and `execfile(...)`, but how do you specify the base directory it should be executing in?

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: why not use `os.chdir` to switch to scriptB's directory, and then switch back after execution completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cwd` parameter, to run scriptB in its directory:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

check_call([scriptB], cwd=os.path.dirname(scriptB))
```